# How to modify an existing txt.file in c++ and output with an updated file? C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to modify an existing text file in C++ , but I am running into the problem that my output file looks messed up. I know the problem is where my else statement is because it includes lines that not from my previous files, but I just don't know how to implement it. Please Help!

Output before modifying:

Josh

Green

Math

M

Output after modifying

JoshKate    Love

English

E

MathM

```
 case '3' :
    {
        continueInput = 'Y';

        ofstream outFile("replaced.txt");
        ifstream readFile("student.txt");
        while(continueInput =='Y' || continueInput == 'y')
        {

            cout << "\t\tEnter the last name of the student: "<<endl;
                           cin >> searchLastName;

            while(getline(readFile, line1))
            {
                if(line1 == searchLastName)
                {
                    cout << "Enter a new First Name"<<endl;
                    cin >> pReplace.firstName;
                    outFile <<pReplace.firstName<< "\t";

                    cout <<"\tEnter a new Last Name  : "<<endl;
                    cin >> pReplace.lastName;
                    outFile << pReplace.lastName<<endl;

                    cout <<"\tEnter a new Course     : "<<endl;
                    cin >> pReplace.className;
                    outFile <<pReplace.className<<endl;

                    cout <<"\tEnter a new Section    : "<<endl<<endl;
                    cin >> pReplace.section;
                    outFile << pReplace.section<<endl;

                    continue;
                }
                else
                    outFile <<line1;
            }

            cout << "Modify another record? (Y/N)"<<endl;
            fflush(stdin);
            continueInput = getchar();
            remove("student.txt");
            rename("replaced.txt","student.txt");
        }

        break;
    }
```

Comment: You haven’t explained how it’s “messed up” or included your code so we can’t help you here. Please edit the question and include the code (as text, properly formatted)

Comment: My code is in the link.

Comment: @josh020 please avoid to include code as images since it will be harder for other users to have a look at it. (copy / paste etc)

Comment: Have you tried to open your output file: `outFile.open()` before writing to it? With this you can also check if something goes wrong when trying to open it.

Comment: Yes, I have. It still doesn't work.

Comment: I was trying to edit your code, and just saw where your `break` is at! , Do you think it is perfectly where it needs to be? and what is the last `}` for? Edit: thank you now it makes more sense

Comment: In Xcode, they said I need to have it for the each case within the switch statement

Comment: Discuss with [your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) what will happen if the user searches, elects to search again, and then inputs a name to search for that is in the list before the name previously searched.

Comment: Craft a [mre] and if making the MRE doesn't reveal the error and solution to you, edit the question to include the MRE. If you haven't tried to find the bug by isolating the bug, you're asking for help too soon.

Comment: Show us the output as either image or add it exactly as it appears on console here in the question. So, people can figure out the problem for you. Also, if will highly increase your chances of getting a solution

Comment: I just updated my question. It has various outputs.